# Return sequence number after Insert query using stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am developing win form application using Oracle database (client requirements). I have used Typed data sets. I have creadted a stored procedure for insertion of record and generating a auto incremented no. using sequence. Its working fine when i test it on Oracle SQL developer. But when i access this stored procedure using typed data sets - records are inserting but i am getting null in place of sequence no.

I also tried it using Oracle Command but it saying -

```
PLS-00201: identifier 'INSERTORDER' must be declared
```

where INSERTORDER is stored procedure name.

Here is the code to access it via typed data sets. Inserting but returning 0 or null.

```
   decimal? result = null;
   Int64 i = Convert.ToInt64(order.INSERTORDER("ord-678", "shyam", out result));
```

Here is the stored procedure working fine on oracle sql developer.

```
 create or replace PROCEDURE INSERTORDER 
(
  ORDERNO IN VARCHAR2 
, CUSTMNAME IN VARCHAR2 
, ORDERID OUT NUMBER 
) AS 
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO orderdetails (orderno, customername)
VALUES (ORDERNO, CUSTMNAME)
returning orderid-1 into ORDERID;
END INSERTORDER;
```

aand here is the oracle command code to access stored procedure - (saying identifier 'INSERTORDER' must be declared)

```
 try
            {

                string connStringIMDB = "DATA SOURCE=192.168.1.14:1521/xe;DBA PRIVILEGE=SYSDBA;PASSWORD=FidelisBazaSLO_SODO;USER ID=FIDELISBAZASLO_SODO";
                OracleConnection objConn = new OracleConnection(connStringIMDB);
                OracleCommand objCmd = new OracleCommand();
                objCmd.Connection = objConn;
                objCmd.CommandText = "INSERTORDER";
                objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                objCmd.Parameters.Add("ORDERNO", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = "20";
                objCmd.Parameters.Add("CUSTMNAME", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = "sadjsah";
                objCmd.Parameters.Add("ORDERID", OracleDbType.Long).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                objConn.Open();
                objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                System.Console.WriteLine("Number of employees in department 20 is {0}", objCmd.Parameters["ORDERID"].Value);
                objConn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {

            }
```

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: You need to create a FUNCTION, not a PROCEDURE.  Procedures dont have return vaules.

Comment: I am using OUT Parameters in stored procedure and it returns value.

Comment: As you can see in stored procedure its - "ORDERID OUT NUMBER"